# Getting Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded Error in Satisfiable Recursive Function

Tags: javascript, recursion

The code is supposed to output a random string from the array [Non-Repeating] each time the function is called, but it sometimes outputs undefined, and there seems to be no pattern. After a certain number of calls I get a "Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded" which I think is from an unsatisfiable recursive function but I'm not sure.

```
var Reasons = ["You're the best Cook", "You're the best Mommas", "You call me the greatest names", "You're the most Stable", "You are super funny most of the time, even though it's not on purpose sometimes", "You keep Daddy's weight in check", "You just are.", "You print money.", "You're super patient", "You're super calm alawys", "You are very quiet on the phone", "You're super up to date on all the new music", "You laugh at things I say that just aren't funny."];
var checkIfRandom = new Array();

function getRandom() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    if (checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum) !== -1) {
        getRandom();
        return;
    } else if (checkIfRandom.indexOf(randomNum) == -1) {
        checkIfRandom.push(randomNum);
        return (randomNum);
    }
};

function writeWord() {
    document.getElementById("reasons").innerHTML = Reasons[getRandom()] + "<br >";
};
```

Code In Action: http://jsfiddle.net/Luyfdcto/

Comment: Maybe you called `writeWord` more than twelve times and it doesn't find an unused index?

Comment: Well, `return;` *does* return `undefined`. Maybe you wanted to return the result of your recursive call?

Comment: What is expected result of `Reasons[getRandom()]` ?

Comment: instead of `getRandom(); return;`, why shouldn't you use `return getRandom();` instead?